# Creating a form-field which redirect users to a sub-directory

Tags: forms, redirect, field

I want to create a simple "form":

1. first row : "user-name"
2. user types his username
3. and there's a "GO" button.
4. when a user clicks "GO" button it'll redirect him to a "sub-directory" (which is already created) named after the "username".

For example, if my domain is asking.com, and I typed "glorious" into the "username" field when I click "GO" - it'll redirect me to : "asking.com/glorious".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
<form>
<label>User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="button" value="Go" id="goBut">
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#goBut').click(function(e){
        var val = $('#username').val();
        window.location = document.URL+val;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, i was trying to say that it didnt work, it does nothing, and on the address bar it says : http://asking.com/form/?username=test.   if i typed "test" on username field.   is there anyway to change that and set a base address to asking.com/form/  ?

Comment: ok, this is what i did :  <form>
<label>User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="button" value="Go" id="goBut">
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#goBut').click(function(e){
var val = $('#username').val();
url = "http://example.com/pica/" + val;
window.location.replace(url);
or
window.location(url);
});
</script>

Comment: when the user clicks on the button it works.  when he press enter on keyboard i get nothing, same page, address bar like this : example.com/pica/un/?username=USER-NAME-WHEN-PRESSING-ENTER-KEY